I need some help setting up BAC0 to communicate as a device
I have this BAC0 sample code, but it generates an error stating something about the datagram of IPv4. I have read the docs and library help files, and part of this seems to work, before it fails.
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
from BAC0 import connect
from BAC0.core.devices.local.factory import analog_input

def defining_objects(device):
    from BAC0.core.devices.local.factory import ObjectFactory
    ObjectFactory.clear_objects()

    analog_input(
        instance=10,
        name="Frequency",
        properties={"units": "hertz"},
        description="Frequency",
        presentValue=18.0,
        relinquish_default=21,
    )
    return device

async def main():
    try:
        # Connect to BAC0 device
        #device1 = connect(ip="192.168.13.193/24", port="47808", deviceId="1110")
        device1 = connect(ip="192.168.13.193/24")
        
        defining_objects(device1)

        while True:
            device1["Frequency"].presentValue = 42.0  # Test value
            print("Device 1 Frequency:", device1["Frequency"].presentValue)
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

[12/16/24 12:00:06] INFO     2024-12-16 12:00:06,757 - INFO    |    notes.py:267
                             Starting Asynchronous BAC0 version                 
                             2024.09.10 (Lite)                                  
                    INFO     2024-12-16 12:00:06,760 - INFO    |    notes.py:267
                             Using bacpypes3 version 0.0.98                     
                    INFO     2024-12-16 12:00:06,761 - INFO    |    notes.py:267
                             Use BAC0.log_level to adjust verbosity             
                             of the app.                                        
                    INFO     2024-12-16 12:00:06,762 - INFO    |    notes.py:267
                             Ex. BAC0.log_level('silence') or                   
                             BAC0.log_level('error')                            
                    INFO     2024-12-16 12:00:06,786 - INFO    |     Lite.py:164
                             Using ip : 192.168.13.193/24 on port               
                             47808 | broadcast : 192.168.13.255                 
[12/16/24 12:00:06] INFO     2024-12-16 12:00:06,789 - INFO    |    notes.py:267
                             Using default JSON configuration file              
                    INFO     2024-12-16 12:00:06,796 - INFO    |    notes.py:267
                             Registered as BACnet/IP App | mode                 
                             normal                                             
                    INFO     2024-12-16 12:00:06,798 - INFO    |    notes.py:267
                             Device instance (id) : 3056500                     
An error occurred: 'Frequency'
[12/16/24 12:00:06] INFO     2024-12-16 12:00:06,802 - INFO    |    notes.py:267
                             Installing recurring task Ping Task                
                             (id:128923930364320)                               
Exception in callback IPv4DatagramServer.set_broadcast_transport_protocol(<IPv4Address 192.168.13.193>)(<Task cancell...nit__.py:150>>)
handle: <Handle IPv4DatagramServer.set_broadcast_transport_protocol(<IPv4Address 192.168.13.193>)(<Task cancell...nit__.py:150>>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eric/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bacpypes3/ipv4/__init__.py", line 159, in retrying_create_datagram_endpoint
    return await loop.create_datagram_endpoint(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1385, in create_datagram_endpoint
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1369, in create_datagram_endpoint
    sock.bind(local_address)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eric/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bacpypes3/ipv4/__init__.py", line 167, in retrying_create_datagram_endpoint
    await asyncio.sleep(BACPYPES_ENDPOINT_RETRY_INTERVAL)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 605, in sleep
    return await future
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/home/eric/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bacpypes3/ipv4/__init__.py", line 207, in set_broadcast_transport_protocol
    transport, protocol = task.result()
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
Exception in callback IPv4DatagramServer.set_local_transport_protocol(<IPv4Address 192.168.13.193>)(<Task cancell...nit__.py:150>>)
handle: <Handle IPv4DatagramServer.set_local_transport_protocol(<IPv4Address 192.168.13.193>)(<Task cancell...nit__.py:150>>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eric/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bacpypes3/ipv4/__init__.py", line 159, in retrying_create_datagram_endpoint
    return await loop.create_datagram_endpoint(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1402, in create_datagram_endpoint
    await waiter
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/home/eric/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bacpypes3/ipv4/__init__.py", line 176, in set_local_transport_protocol
    transport, protocol = task.result()
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError


------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue

I don't know if I can even use my wifi card as a bacnet server with BAC0. I am just looking for help on how to properly configure BAC0 to report a value which I can use YABE to monitor across a network.

You must use the IP addrewss of an active network interface on your machine and port 47808 must not be used already (like if YABE is on...)
